# How to create a scripting system for a class in python?

Tags: python, class

I am wondering if it is possible to create an object that holds functions such as this one:

```
class Script:
    def update(self):
        print(True)
```

and I could add it to a parent class, like this one:

```
class Engine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scripts = [Script()]
```

How would I make all scripts in the scripts list run their functions every frame?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a match for the registry pattern. Basically, you have to keep a store somewhere of all the 'Script' subclasses you create, so that you can later execute them. There's a couple ways to approach it- this one's relatively straightforward-

```
# main.py
__registry = []

def register_class(cls):
  __registry.append(cls)


class Script:
  pass
```

---

```
 # subclass.py
    
    from main import Script, register
    
    @register
    class SubScript(Script):
      pass
```

---

```
# runner.py
from main import __registry

for cls in __registry:
  cls.run()
```

Another approach uses the `__init_subclass__` method to store the subclass on the registry object directly-

```
_subclasses = []


class Script:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        _subclasses.append(cls)

    @classmethod
    def run_all(cls):
        for cls in _subclasses:
            cls.run()


class SubScript(Script):
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        print("a")


Script.run_all()
```

The final approach would be to do the same, but using a metaclass (though the magic init methods keep allowing me to drop metaclasses from my code, so I would probably prefer that)

One caveat with all three methods- if a file doesn't get imported, the registry doesn't know about it. You can put code into your main file to search the directory and import all the modules, but it won't just happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can import dynamically your modules classes and excecute their `run()` methods if they're a subclass of the main class.

Here is an example:

Having this tree structure:

```
.
├── main.py
├── new_script.py
└── script.py
```

**script.py:**

```
import os

class Script:
    def run(self):
        print('Running Script class')

    def run_all(self):
        print('Running all scritps from Script class')
        # you can improve listing valid files for your case
        valid_files = [
            k.split('.')[0] for k in os.listdir() if (
                not k.startswith('__') and not k.endswith('__') and (
                    k != __file__.split(os.sep)[-1]
                )
            )
        ]
        for file_name in valid_files:
            module = __import__(file_name)
            # listing all attributes of the module
            for k in dir(module):
                cls = getattr(module, k)
                # Check if cls have __name__ attribute
                if hasattr(cls, '__name__'):
                    # the imported attribute should be a class
                    # and should not be the current module class
                    if isinstance(cls, type) and (
                        cls.__name__ != self.__class__.__name__
                    ):
                        # if the imported module is a subclass
                        # of the current class; then excecute run method
                        if issubclass(cls, self.__class__):
                            cls.run(cls)
```

**new_script.py:**

```
from script import Script


class NewScript(Script):
    def run(self):
        print('Running newScript')
```

**main.py:**

```
from script import Script


if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = Script()
    instance.run_all()
```

Demo:

```
$> python main.py
```

Output:

```
Running all scritps from Script class
Running newScript
```

Comment: In case the `file_name = 'a.b.c'` you've to reload the module multiple times in order to point to the latest module file like this example: `for k in file_name.split('.')[1:]: module = getattr(module, k)`